# secret detection in gitlab ci, needs a runner I cant get it to run

Tags: gitlab-ci

Really new to gitlab CI, i'm currently struggling to figure out how to get the secret stage to run it keeps saying i need to configure a runner, the pipeline gets stuck

This job is stuck because the project doesn't have any runners online assigned to it.

If i set the tag to docker it runs but it doesn't seem to work..any ideas?

I added the following to the gitlab ci file

```
include:
  - template: Security/Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml
```

When i add the above pipeline get stuck stating it has no runners assigned to run this.

Comment: Is this self-hosted or on gitlab.com shared runners? If on gitlab.com and you don't have your own self-hosted runner, you probably don't want to use `tags:` -- What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? -- Please include any relevant error messages and your CI configuration file.

Comment: Do you also have the corresponding stage enabled in the stages section? The documentation should outline a stage required.

Comment: its becuase none of my runners have a tag of 'secret' associated with them, which the step in the stage required by defualt, how do i set a tag on a runner?

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the runner to [Secret detection](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/#enable-secret-detection) job. See below:

```
include:
  - template: Jobs/Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml

secret_detection:
  tags:
    - docker # the example tag name of Gitlab runner by Docker executor
```

If you would like to change the stage

```
 secret_detection:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker
```